# Add style to key value in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I am wondering how I can add style to a mapped value in a key value.

Here is the code:

```
enderModelSummary() {
    const modelSummaryArr = []

     for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.props.adminLogData)){
         modelSummaryArr.push(`${key}:  ${value}`)
    }
     const modelSummaryData = modelSummaryArr.map(data => {
        return <div className='row'>{data}</div>
     })
     return modelSummaryData
}
```

I only want to make the `${value}` red. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably wrapping around with a `<span>` tag and styling it to `{ color: 'red' }` would do the job. Also you need to wrap around with [Fragement `<></>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to have a proper **JSX** syntax in the array:

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

Try as the following:

```
modelSummaryArr.push(
 <>
   {`${key}: `}
   <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>
     {value}
   </span>
 </>
)
```

Comment: @infantrygarrett Cool, happy to help! :)